# Linking SDL in a C program

Tags: c, sdl

I have recently become interested in using SDL after having learned some basics of C. I have installed SDL_image and SDL_mixer. They are located in /usr/local/include/SDL2. I realize that you must link against the header files however I am not sure how to do it. I am getting the error that SDL_mixer or SDL_image do not exist (depending on their line order in my source code). I have tried two different compilation commands and neither work here they are:

```
gcc filename.c -o test -I./include -L./usr/local/include/SDL2 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL_mixer -lSDL_image

gcc filename.c -o test -I./usr/local/include/SDL2 -L./lib -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL_mixer -lSDL_image
```

If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you do not want that leading period

wrong

```
gcc filename.c -o test -I./include -L./usr/local/include/SDL2 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL_mixer -lSDL_image
```

closer - not necessarily correct yet

```
gcc filename.c -o test  -L/usr/local/include/SDL2 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL_mixer -lSDL_image
```

any path with a leading period indicates to start from current dir and go relative instead of the intended absolute path

any system has the notion of a default library path which is fine if you are using a standard install ... so no need to do a

```
-I/include
```

... sometime a library has helpers to identify and auto populate these ...

sdl and sdl2 do have such a helper ...  this will give you those settings

```
gcc -o test filename.c  `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2`
```

notice those backticks ... another syntax style would be

```
gcc -o test filename.c  $(pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2)
```

you are free to issue that stand alone just to take a peek

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2
```

... output

```
-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lSDL2
```

Now onto your sdl mixer ... well it has a

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs SDL2_mixer
```

... output

```
-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2
```

you probably do not want to mix sdl with sdl2 so replace mention of

```
-lSDL_mixer -lSDL_image
```

with

```
-lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_image
```

as per

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs SDL2_image
```

... output

```
-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2
```

so bundling these together

```
gcc -o test filename.c  -lSDL2main $(pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2) $(pkg-config --cflags --libs SDL2_mixer)  $(pkg-config --cflags --libs SDL2_image)
```

or more simply combined to

```
gcc -o test filename.c -lSDL2main $(pkg-config --cflags --libs  sdl2 SDL2_mixer SDL2_image )
```

this can be stripped down to simply the following ... yet above syntax is more robust to changes

```
gcc -o test filename.c -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2  -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_mixer  -lSDL2_image
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed answer. I haven't tried this yet but I am sure it will work!

Comment: The `pkg-config` can be combined `$(pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2 SDL2_mixer)`

Comment: @Scott Stensland Hey Scott, I just used the following compilation command as you had suggested: gcc -o test filename.c -lSDL2main $(pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2 SDL2_mixer SDL2_image) and it compiled but when it came to testing the program I triggered an error. Upon testing my program I got an error that reported that I have no available video device. Any ideas?

Comment: @Scott Stensland Here [it is](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/40ee6dccfe0a2829b0a74c32c038d601). Thanks again. You're going to have to forgive my half-baked C code.

Comment: @TheCrifix  half-baked is better than no-bake !!!   its generating a window just fine,  not getting any video device error when compiling/executing both local as well as on a remote server ... are you on a laptop ? paste down the exact error

Comment: @Scott Stensland The exact error I am getting is the one I am generating through the game_init function. In that function I initialize SDL and check to see if the value is above zero (i.e everything initialized properly). The error message is as follows: SDL error -> No available video device. To specify I am working on a MS surface pro 3 on Windows 8.1 running a Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit virtual environment on Oracle VM Virtual Box. I have done a bit of searching as well. It seems that some people get this error when they don't have X11 but I don't know what that is exactly.

Comment: issue ...  sudo apt-get install xorg-dev  ... to give you X11 ... it might be a good time to install ubuntu along side M$ to give yourself a dual boot instead of running ubuntu as a child process of M$ ... just backup first ... I put everything I need on Dropbox which frees up ability to reinstall ubuntu at will

Comment: @Scott Stensland Just recompiled and reran but I got the same error after I installed the package you suggested. Is it possible there is anything else I might need? I compiled SDL and all the component parts from source. Should I perhaps recompile?

Comment: sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev
    ...   Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138438/discussion-between-scott-stensland-and-thecrifix).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sdl2-config` to supply the appropriate flags to gcc:

```
gcc filename.c -o test `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
```

`sdl2-config --cflags` produces a list of options that should be passed to the compiler, and `sdl2-config --libs` produces a list of libraries that should be linked to.